# Android browser red lines at the bottom and right side

Tags: browser

When using chromium I get a red line at the bottom and right side (Not the square red frame set by strict mode), within the rendered web page when viewing some pages requiring WebGL. What does it mean? It usually doesn't appear right away when loading the site and takes a while but even after it appears, the WebGL apps seem to continue working properly.

An example of such a site is http://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/lots-o-images/index.html.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include what device and Android version you're using, and ideally a screenshot of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I see your problem on Chrome for Android.

Looking at the stylesheet (CSS) of the page on Firefox browser for PC, I see that the background color of the page is red. I can't be sure with Chrome for Android, but it could be that there is a margin at the right and bottom side, and the application did not take up that space. That's why you see red.